# Is there any way to work on same project of android studio on diffrent pc's when i am trying this i am getting an error?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to work on the same project of Android studio with different pcs but when I try to run my project I am getting an error `C:\Users\Mayank Gupta\.android\debug.keystore` (The system cannot find the path specified)

Any solutions

Comment: did you delete debug.keystore file ?

Comment: also path should be C:\Users\Mayank Gupta\.android\debug.keystore . Check if the file exists .

Comment: generate signed apk and change the path according to your keystore

Comment: did you search regarding the same on [Like This](https://www.google.com/search?q=open+same+Android+Studio+project+in+Different+PC&oq=open+same+Android+Studio+project+in+Different+PC)

Comment: current path is "C:\Users\akanksha\.android\debug.keystore " where i can update this in in my pc

Answer (score 1):

when you change pc then you have to check your path for  `debug.keystore`. if `debug.keystore` is not at same path then you have to update path.